# Do I necessarily need coordinates for spatial prediction?

Tags: interpolation, spatial-statistics, terminology

Commonly, it is stated that spatial prediction is the same as spatial interpolation, i.e. the estimation of values based on the observations' location:

y ~ lon + lat

Others state, that spatial prediction is more general than spatial interpolation, allowing also for other covariates:

y ~ lon + lat + x1 + x2

My question is: Do I really need the coordinates as covariates in order to have a spatial prediction model? For instance, isn't the following model also a spatial prediction model if the covariates x1 and x2 are "spatial", meaning that they have some relation to space (like measuring the distance to a certain feature or the amount of greenspace within a certain buffer):

y ~ x1 + x2

If yes, wouldn't this make basically every model using real-world data a spatial prediction model?

Comment: What you are suggesting is actually a method of creating "dummy variables" in order to create a traditional Ordinary Least Squares / Regression Analysis, see jgm_GIS' more correct statistical description below.

Answer (score 5):

The spatial prediction aims at predicting a variable **where it has not been observed**. Therefore you need to know the coordinates of the location where you make the prediction, even if the coordinates are not **explicitly** used to build your predictive model. Based on your example, you need to know the coordinate of your point to compute the distance to a feature, and you need to know the coordinate of the center of your area to compute the amount of greenspace. Therefore, even if you build your model without the coordinates (e.g. not taking spatial autocorrelation into account), it would remain a spatial prediction if you apply it to location where it has not been observed. On the other hand, if you don't care about the location of the prediction (you just want to predict your variable under the hypothetical condition that the greenspace percentage is 50 % and the distance to a road is 100 m), then your model is not strictly speaking a spatial prediction.

As a remark, I recommand not using lat/long (degree) in spatial prediction models because it adds a lot of complexity to compute areas and distances. It is better to use a (local) cartesian system (meters).

Answer (score 4):

In your example of y ~ x1 + x2, x1 is an independent variable this is perfectly collinear to the lat lon.

X2 is also perfectly collinear to the spatial variables used to calculate the amount of greenspace.

So, I would say that y ~ x1 + x2 is a non spatial model with perfectly multicollinear, omitted, spatial variables.

You could create a spatial lag model (or some other type) with greenspace as a variable that might have similar results to y ~ x1 + x2.  However, if you know that x1 and x2 are good predictors of y and your model doesn't have a spatial autocorrelation problem, why would you?

Answer (score 2):

As far as my knowledge goes, `spatial interpolation` is one of the most-used `spatial prediction` techniques that researcher are using for both spatial pattern recognition and predicting the behavior of natural phenomena in study area. Consider `air pollution` as an example that scientists need to predict in a specific urban area when they observe quality indexes continuously through monitoring stations scattered city-wide.

Based on **Tobler's First Law of Geography** introduced by an *American-Swiss geographer and cartographer*, **Waldo R. Tobler**, measured relation, say linkage between industrial areas and `SO2` emissions in a specific location `(X0,Y0)`, is affected by other neighboring locations `(Xi,Yi)`. Consequently, during the research we need to calculate the surrounding effects by giving an appropriate weight to each neighborhood `(i)`. This weight should be larger for near locations which means the effect of close locations are much stronger than far ones.

Such calculations comes from concepts known as **Spatial Auto-correlation** and **Spatial Heterogeneity** that are measured by global and local **Moran Indexes** respectively. These indexes fall between `-1` and `+1` and show the strength of spatial correlation globally and locally. To achieve a precise and accurate regression model, we need to reduce the `unbiased errors` while the coefficients of regression model are computed. To do so, we have to consider global and local spatial dependencies between observations while coefficients are estimated.

Find a review of these concepts in my research through [this link](https://iwaponline.com/wqrj/article-abstract/53/4/205/63295/Extracting-the-spatio-temporal-linkages-between?redirectedFrom=fulltext). There are also some more information here:

[https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/9781118786352.wbieg1011.pub2#:~:text=This%20discussion%20of%20Tobler's%20first,published%20by%20Tobler%20in%201970](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/9781118786352.wbieg1011.pub2#:%7E:text=This%20discussion%20of%20Tobler%27s%20first,published%20by%20Tobler%20in%201970).
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S088329271930085X.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/geographically-weighted-regression